# undefined function finfo_open, unable to alter php.ini

Tags: php, file, download

Using a CMS and server environment which, long story short, is quite picky about the php.ini and not very friendly to changes in it; so I *am* aware that the standard fix for the "undefined function finfo_open" error is to turn on fileinfo in php.ini. However, that normal solution isn't an option. Is there a good alternative or available class/function/etc. for replacing its functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Bad Luck. There is no polyfill for these functions.

You need to enable the extension `php_fileinfo` to work with the `finfo_*` functions.

Of course, you could try to write the polyfill:

```
if( ! function_exists('finfo_open')) 
{ 
    // re-implement finfo_open in user-space, for use when ext not loaded
}
```

source of ext in php-src: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/fileinfo/fileinfo.c